# Why does this construction of std::function from lambda not compile?

Tags: c++

Why doesnt the following line compile?

```
std::function<void (int)> f = [](int&){};
```

But many other alternatives do:

```
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int&)> f1 = [](const int&){};
    //[[maybe_unused]]
    // doesnt compile because losing constness
    //std::function<void (const int&)> f2 = [](int&){}; 
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int&)> f3 = [](int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int&)> f4 = [](const int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int&)> f5 = [](const int&){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int&)> f6 = [](int&){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int&)> f7 = [](int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int&)> f8 = [](int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int)> f9 = [](const int&){};
    //[[maybe_unused]]
    // doesnt compile because losing constness
    //std::function<void (const int)> f10 = [](int&){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int)> f11 = [](const int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (const int)> f12 = [](int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int)> f13 = [](const int&){};
    //[[maybe_unused]]
    // doesnt compile because ??
    //std::function<void (int)> f14 = [](int&){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int)> f15 = [](const int){};
    [[maybe_unused]]
    std::function<void (int)> f16 = [](int){};
```

My understanding was that std::function have a () operator which takes the args and calls the functor's () operator with the args
so its possible that for e,g, - first one takes const ref and next takes copy.

With this line of logic, I would think that a int copy should be able to be passed forward as int&. Can someone explain?

Comment: `std::function<void (int)> f` can be called with `f(5)`, but the `int &` cannot bind to the `5`.

Comment: @mch but `void (int)` means int is passed by copy, so it should become a lvalue and then it should be able to bind to int&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` [forwards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) it's arguments to it's target. The lambda assigned to `f14` can't be called with an rvalue.

You are also incorrect about `f10`, that [is the same case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf065641560b9cbc) as `f14`. Top level `const` is ignored in arguments. Each of `f11`, `f12`, `f15` and `f16` are the same case.

Comment: "Top level const is ignored in arguments." . Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list)

Comment: You mean `4) Top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped from the parameter type (This adjustment only affects the function type, but doesn't modify the property of the parameter: int f(const int p, decltype(p)*); and int f(int, const int*); declare the same function)`?

Comment: Have been reading about perfect forwarding. From my understanding, in order to receive forwarding reference you must receive `T&&`. So, I thought it should be `std::function::operator()(Args&&...)` instead of `std::function::operator()(Args...)`. What am I missing?

Comment: You have something like `void std::function<void(int)>::operator()(int a) { INVOKE(target, std::forward<int>(a)); }`. You only need the `&&` if you are deducing the type from the arguments, not if it's specified elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I cant find any tutorial/docs/guide about perfect forwarding when not working with the types that do not need to be deduced. Can you again point me somewhere?